# Split management network from data in Xen Server

Tags: networking, virtualization, xen, xenserver

I'm working on configuring our existing pool of four hypervisors running XenServer 6.1 to use a separate management network.

Currently the setup is a single link with a public address over which all VM and management traffic flows.

We're working on changing that to

- An Active/Passive bonded interface for management on a private network
- A separate Active/Passive bonded interface for VM traffic

I'm trying to figure out what the impact will be on the current environment when I make the change and whether anyone has any tips or best practices on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you bond a active interface you will have a drop in comms to your servers.

I would suggest the following,

1. Bring up the bonded pair of eth2 and eth3 on all hypervisors.
2. Ensure that you can ping, etc.
3. Then create a network on each hypervisor that will be using the new eth2-eth3 bonded pair.
4. Move a non critical vm to new virtual network switch and start testing.

Once done, do the same with the management network.

That should work without causing too much of disruption.

Comment: That's what we have up right now, but Xen Server has a single interface - whether a bonded pair or not - that it considers its "Management" interface - with DNS configs, etc - that it uses for communication with the pool.

From what I've read, changing which interface Xen uses for this can lead to some really weird pool errors.